# Basic Spring JDBC application, JdbcTemplate bean not found

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

A bean definition of type `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` was not found, therefore `@Autowired private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;` doesn't actually have a value inside it.
My **Application.java** looks as following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Value("${spring.name}")
private String name;

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

//    @Bean
//    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(ApplicationContext ctx) {
//        return args -> {
//            System.out.printf("The application is running %s!", name);
//        };
//    }

public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {

    log.info("Creating tables");

    jdbcTemplate.execute("DROP TABLE customers IF EXISTS");
    jdbcTemplate.execute("CREATE TABLE customers(" +
            "id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(255), last_name VARCHAR(255))");

    // Split up the array of whole names into an array of first/last names
    List<Object[]> splitUpNames = Arrays.asList("John Woo", "Jeff Dean", "Josh Bloch", "Josh Long").stream()
            .map(name -> name.split(" "))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Use a Java 8 stream to print out each tuple of the list
    splitUpNames.forEach(name -> log.info(String.format("Inserting customer record for %s %s", name[0], name[1])));

    // Uses JdbcTemplate's batchUpdate operation to bulk load data
    jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("INSERT INTO customers(first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)", splitUpNames);

    log.info("Querying for customer records where first_name = 'Josh':");
    jdbcTemplate.query(
            "SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM customers WHERE first_name = ?", new Object[] { "Josh" },
            (rs, rowNum) -> new CustomerModel(rs.getLong("id"), rs.getString("first_name"), rs.getString("last_name"))
    ).forEach(customer -> log.info(customer.toString()));
}
```

I understand Dependency Injection and IoC which should technically instantiate a JdbcTemplate instance by itself, but if I do it manually it I have the following code which gives the error that `JdbcTemplate` bean requires `dataSource` property (which I'm giving as below):

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
private String dbUrl;

@Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
private String dbUsername;

@Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
private String dbPassword;

private DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines are not producing Spring beans, so they are not candidates for autowiring:

```
private DataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);

private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
```

If you're using Spring Boot, you can [follow these instructions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html) to configure your datasource, though make sure you use the spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency in your pom.

If you're configuring these manually, you need to create a @Configuration class, that exposes both a DataSource and JdbcTemplate bean. For example, something like:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {

   @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
   private String dbUrl;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
   private String dbUsername;

   @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
   private String dbPassword;

   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
     return new DriverManagerDataSource(dbUrl, dbUsername, dbPassword);
   }

   @Bean
   public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
     return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was looking into create a Bean definition but couldn't figure out how it would look, and this worked.